# htaccess - Conflicting urls when parent may or may not exist

Tags: .htaccess

I have two urls that are nearly the same but the parent url does not exist in one of them. How do I write it to handle both.

```
overview/app/
products/overview/app/
```

Right now, the first one is conflicting the second, and the second ends up redirecting to the 404 page.

Currently I only have one line of code, not sure how to write the second.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)overview/app/?$ /$1products/app/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: My apologies, forgot to add it in.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your rule. What is the purpose of it? Meaning what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Originally I only setup the first rule `/overview/app/` to send to `/products/app/`. Recently I became there is an old URL that is going to the 404 page, which is `/products/overview/app/` and I want to make sure it also goes to `/products/app/` to make sure users get where they need to go. Does this make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule (^|/)overview/app/?$ /products/app/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

This will match both of these URLs:

```
/products/overview/app/
/overview/app/
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was spit on!